# I want to send terminal print data to database

Tags: python, django, selenium

[image]

I'm new to Django, I have created a selenium project in which It automates mobile recharge. After completion of "recharge successful" I need it to send a successful receipt into my database. I used `print(order_id.text)` to get receipt in my terminal. now I don't know how to send that receipt to my database.

Comment: Your `amazonpay` function calls are specified *before* the view?

Comment: Welcome to SO! please help us help you by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please also provide more details as to 1) what database you are using 2) how do these two scripts relate. Thanks!

Comment: i am using sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to implement this is with a [*custom management command* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management). In your `amazon` app, yoou can define a management command:

```
amazon/
    management/
        commands/
            amazonpay.py
    # …
```

In that `amazonpay.py` file, you then implement the custom management command:

```
# amazon/management/commands.amazonpay.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from amazon.models import Amazon

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Some description...'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # … run selenium …
        Amazon.objects.create(
            o=ord_id
        )
```

You can then run this command with:

```
python3 manage.py amazonpay
```

In fact `runserver`, `makemigrations`, etc. are all defined as management commands as well.

Comment: moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'
do I have to install any kind of lib.?
as i have already mentioned my app in setting.py

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: @srfreak: if you run `manage.py runserver` with `--settings` then of course you need to do the same for `amazonpay`.

Comment: TypeError: create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @srfreak: but you should use `o=ord_id`, not `ord_id`, and the `Amazon` model of course needs to have a field named `o`.

Comment: sir, Can u tell me, how can create a link for localhost so that I can execute selenium in postman. I tried http.server as it only executes text file